# Fatal error, any idea how to solve the problem?

Tags: php, fatal-error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, bool given in D:\xampp\htdocs\ss\php-login-simple-master\php-login-simple-master\login.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ss\php-login-simple-master\php-login-simple-master\login.php on line 18

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUUG4.png)

it is a login and it works but when you write wrong the username and password, that error appears

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a bool value to a function that expects an iterable object, in this case the error is in the `count($results)`.
You need to change the way you evaluate the login.